# MySql select from 3 tables Undefined index error

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables **tbl_user,tbl_supplier,tbl_subcontractor**

I want to select this rows from

**tbl_user** (*db_fname,db_lname*),

**tbl_supplier**(*db_CompanyName*),

**tbl_subcontractor**(*db_CompanyName*)

I'm using this query

```
SELECT concat(db_fname,' ',db_lname) as fname from tbl_user)
      UNION 
      (SELECT db_CompanyName as scn from tbl_supplier)
      UNION 
      (SELECT db_CompanyName as sucn from tbl_subcontractor)
```

It give me the correct result but also give me this error

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: scn in
>   C:\wamp\www\order\projectmanagment\transferred.php on line 48 Call
>   Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0021260912{main}( 
>   )..\transferred.php:0    ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: sucm in
>   C:\wamp\www\order\projectmanagment\transferred.php on line 49 Call
>   Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0021260912{main}( 
>   )..\transferred.php:0

the result of this query will be display on a select menu like this:

```
echo'<select name="txt_transferredto" class="states">';
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
         $fname=$row['fname'];
         $companyname=$row['scn'];
         $subcompanyname=$row['sucm'];
      if($fname!=""){
       echo"<option value='$fname'>";echo $fname;echo"</option>";}
    else if($subcompanyname!=""){      
        echo"<option value='$subcompanyname'>";echo $subcompanyname;echo"</option>";}
    else if($companyname!=""){      
        echo"<option value='$companyname'>";echo $companyname;echo"</option>";}
      }
      echo'</select>';
```

in this menu appear the result but also the error

i can select from this menu the data take it from **tbl_user** and do what ever i want but also if i select data take it from **tbl_supplier** or **tbl_subcontractor** i can't do anything(update or select or ...)

i test on sql and give me result but i don't know what is this problem 
How to solve this Problem

> ```
> $q=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT concat(db_fname,' ' , db_lname) as fname from tbl_user ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
>  $qq= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT db_CompanyName as scn from tbl_supplier") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
>  $qqq= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT db_CompanyNamee as sucn from tbl_subcontractor") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
>
>   echo'<select name="txt_transferred" class="form-control inpu-md">';
>  echo'<option value="">--SELECT--</option>';
>   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q) and $roww=mysqli_fetch_array($qq) and $rowww=mysqli_fetch_array($qqq)){
>      $fname=$row['fname'];
>      $companyname=$roww['scn'];
>      $subcompanyname=$rowww['sucn'];
>   if($fname!=""){
>    echo"<option value='$fname'>";echo $fname;echo"</option>";}
> else if($subcompanyname!=""){      
>     echo"<option value='$subcompanyname'>";echo $subcompanyname;echo"</option>";}
> else if($companyname!=""){      
>     echo"<option value='$companyname'>";echo $companyname;echo"</option>";}
>   }
>
>   echo'</select>';
> ```

Comment: Your query result will have only one field called fname, it's a good idea to run queries separately before inserting them in code so you see what you are getting back.

Comment: @Marco i run it out side the same result and it's the result i want but the problem is with the error i post it here

Comment: when you run your query outside do you see any field called 'scn' ?

Comment: @Marco yes i see it the field is select from this query and also appear on the php page but with this error i put it

Comment: the error arrives because the result has only one field and you are trying to access 3..

Comment: @Marco How i solve this?

Comment: @Marco Any help please

Comment: Sorry no idea how to help you

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be:

```
SELECT concat(db_fname,' ',db_lname) as fname , 
S.db_CompanyName as scn,   SC.db_CompanyNam as sucn 
FROM tbl_user U,  tbl_supplier S, tbl_subcontractor SC
```

Comment: this query not show any error but it print result in the select menu many time not one time for each row it print xxx more than one time and xxx is only exist once

Comment: this is because you dont have the key, which user tie with which supplier and subcontractor. So it will select all from tbl_user,tbl_supplier & tbl_subcontractor

Comment: but this 3 tables don't have any relation between us i can't solve this problem to not repeat the names in the select menu ?! it print like this  fadi fadi fadi company1 company1 company1 like this for all names in this tables and this tables don't have any relation

Comment: yes. because there is no relation between these 3 tables. your record will be fname1,company1,company1,  fname2,company1,company1. the way to solve it, is split  mysqli_fetch_array($q) into 3 sql query and put into 3 array variables. then you compare the variables

Comment: can you please give me an example how to do your idea ?!

Comment: can you please check above i do this code but it didn't give me a result